# Retrieving next post in query

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Attempting to output the next two posts in the query of WP posts and I think I'm a bit stuck. I was attempting to retrieve the ID of the post where if the current post is found, output the next two posts in the query but it seems I'm only outputting the first two posts following that.

```
<?php
     $test_args = array(
       'post_type' => 'hsm_testimonial',
       'posts_per_page' => 3,
       'order' => 'DESC',       
     );
     $current_post = get_the_ID(); 
     $test_query = new WP_Query( $test_args );
     if ($test_query->have_posts() ): 
     while ($test_query->have_posts() ): $test_query->the_post(); 
     if ($current_post == get_the_ID() ) : ?>           
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="wellness-item flexbox flex-center flex-column">
            <hr class="line">
            <h3 class="text-center font-serif weight-semibold"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <div class="text-center text-xxl font-serif weight-bold">&ldquo;</div>
            <div class="text-center testimonial"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> </div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="text-center center-block">Read More</a>
            <div class="text-xxl text-center font-serif weight-bold">&rdquo;</div>
        </div>
<?php endif; endwhile; $test_query->reset_postdata(); endif; $test_query->reset_query();  ?>
```

Any assistance/input will be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to get the 3 next hsm_testimonials. 
Try something white the `posts_where` filter.

Code example:

```
<?php
    //Where id is greater then
    function filter_id_greater_then($where){
        if( get_the_ID() ){
            $where .= " AND ID >".get_the_ID();            
        }
        return $where;
    }

    //Query args
     $test_args = array(
       'post_type' => 'hsm_testimonial',
       'posts_per_page' => 3,
       'order' => 'DESC',       
     );

     //The query
     add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_id_greater_then');
     $test_query = new WP_Query( $test_args );
     remove_filter('posts_where' , 'filter_id_greater_then');
?>

<?php if ($test_query->have_posts() ): ?>

    <!--The loop-->
    <?php while ($test_query->have_posts() ): $test_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="wellness-item flexbox flex-center flex-column">
            <hr class="line">
            <h3 class="text-center font-serif weight-semibold"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <div class="text-center text-xxl font-serif weight-bold">&ldquo;</div>
            <div class="text-center testimonial"><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="text-center center-block">Read More</a>
            <div class="text-xxl text-center font-serif weight-bold">&rdquo;</div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!--End of the loop-->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Sincerely appreciate the help on this but I seem to be getting an error.

: Undefined variable: curent_post in
/Users/user/sites/hsmwp-content/themes/hsm/single-hsm_testimonial.php
on line
45

Comment: Followed by -> 
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY hsm_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3' at line 1]
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS hsm_posts.ID FROM hsm_posts WHERE 1=1 AND hsm_posts.post_type = 'hsm_testimonial' AND (hsm_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR hsm_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR hsm_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ID > ORDER BY hsm_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 3

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the code (just updated it).